# Efficient numpy way of assigning index to True values in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for an efficient way of assigning column index where the value is true in the Matrix.

Let us say that we have the following Array:

```
np.array([[True,False, True],
          [True,False, True],
          [True,False, True]])
```

I would like to have the following:

```
np.array([[0,0, 2],
          [0,0, 2],
          [0,0, 2]])
```

for loops are not efficient and enough.
I assume something with np.where, but how to combine this efficiently?

Comment: You understand that Numpy arrays expect every element to be the same type, yes?

Comment: Vallid point, but it will convert booleans to 0 and ones automatically. Still i would be intreseted with the conversion how it would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np
input_array = np.array([[True,False, True], [True,False, True], [True,False, True]])
height, width = input_array.shape
indices = np.arange(width)
indices = np.vstack([indices]*height)
output_array = np.where(input_array, indices, input_array)
print(output_array)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 2]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 0 2]]
```

Explanation: I first prepare indices which is in this case:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Then use `np.where` as suggested.